# How to get windows caption in kernel mode?

Tags: winapi, kernel

I've got hwnd through NtUserGetThreadState, and tested with NtUserDestroyWindow.
But I can't get windows caption text by using NtUserInternalGetWindowText or by sending WM_GETTEXT using NtUserMessageCall.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to allocate memory in target process.

By using ZwAllocateVirtualMemory to allocate memory in target process, it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d69/include_2reactos_2win32k_2ntuser_8h_a2d68b71d5c8fa7a56bd33c0145b53876.html#a2d68b71d5c8fa7a56bd33c0145b53876) site, the signature of `NtUserInternalGetWindowText` is :

```
INT NTAPI NtUserInternalGetWindowText (HWND  hWnd, 
                                       LPWSTR  lpString,
                                       INT nMaxCount)
```

**First :**

Can't you debug to understand what append.

**Second :**

Do you take care of the fact it use unicode string